# Beautiful soup how select <a href> and <td> elements with whitespaces

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to select the date, url, description, and additional url from table and am having trouble accessing them given the weird white spaces:

So far I've written:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup('https://www.sec.gov/litigation/litreleases/litrelarchive/litarchive2010.shtml')

test1 = soup.findAll("td", {"nowrap" : "nowrap"})
test2 = [item.text.strip() for item in test1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no class or id HTML attribute to quickly identify the table to scrape; after experimentation I found it was the table at index 4.

Next we ignore the header by separating it from the data, which still has table rows that are just separations for quarters. We can skip over these using a try-except block since those only contain one table data tag.

I noticed that the description is separated by tabs, so I split the text on  `\t`.

For the urls, I used `.get('href')` rather than `['href']` since not every anchor tag has an href attribute from my experience scraping. This avoids errors should that case occur. Finally the second anchor tag does not always appear, so this is wrapped in a try-except block as well.

```
data = []
table = soup.find_all('table')[4] # target the specific table
header, *rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    try:
        litigation, date, complaint = row.find_all('td')
    except ValueError:
        continue # ignore quarter rows

    id = litigation.text.strip().split('-')[-1]
    date = date.text.strip()
    desc = complaint.text.strip().split('\t')[0]
    lit_url = litigation.find('a').get('href')

    try:
        comp_url = complaint.find('a').get('href')
    except AttributeError:
        comp_ulr = None # complaint url is optional

    info = dict(id=id, date=date, desc=desc, lit_url=lit_url, comp_url=comp_url)
    data.append(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use :has and nth-of-type in combination with next_sibling to get those columns

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests, re

def make_soup(url):
    the_page = requests.get(url)
    soup_data = BeautifulSoup(the_page.content, "html.parser")
    return soup_data

soup = make_soup('https://www.sec.gov/litigation/litreleases/litrelarchive/litarchive2010.shtml')
releases = []
links = []
dates = []
descs = [] 
addit_urls = []

for i in soup.select('td:nth-of-type(1):has([href^="/litigation/litreleases/"])'):
    sib_sib = i.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
    releases+= [i.a.text]
    links+= [i.a['href']]
    dates += [i.next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip()]
    descs += [re.sub('\t+|\s+',' ',sib_sib.text.strip())]
    addit_urls += ['N/A' if sib_sib.a is None else sib_sib.a['href']]

result = list(zip(releases, links, dates, descs, addit_urls))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank your for taking the time to show me that I can use the next_sibling!